# WPF does not rebind if new datacontext Equals() previous datacontext

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

As explained on http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/DataRefreshInWPF.aspx

A WPF control sometimes does not rebind to the new datacontext. Specifically when using viewmodels that implement `Object.Equals` to see if viewmodels are logically equal. The problem here is that the control does not rebind to the new datacontext if it is logically equal to the previous. This causes the controls to become limp, they are not bound to the new viewmodel.

I circumvented this by first setting the `DataContext` to a `new object()`. This makes sure the control rebinds to the new datacontext. This does not work however when a viewmodel contains another viewmodel that implements `Object.Equals`. A view bound to that viewmodel using a `DataTemplate` will not rebind. How can I work around this?

Obviously WPF databinding should use `ReferenceEquals` instead of `Equals`..

**UPDATE:** I solved it for now by having the sub ViewModels implement `IEquatable<T>` instead of overriding `Object.Equals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for now by having the sub ViewModels implement IEquatable instead of overriding Object.Equals.